# I would like a git log with author, number of lines changed and message

Tags: git, logging, statistics

I would like to see how much each developer did recently and spot some patterns in the code. I've been trying to find git command but somehow it eludes me.

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --numstat
```

This one comes very close, it lists commits and files (I would be fine with commit and number of changes), number of lines changed, the only thing missing is adding author to the mix.

Is there an easy way to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a format instead of decorate:

```
 git log --graph --oneline --format="%d %s (%an)" --numstat
```

See more at [`git log` "commit formatting"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting): `%an` is the author name

Comment: @ZeljkoDakic You can tweak the format string in order to add as many field as you need.